# Как сделать, чтобы при смене радиокнопки прошлое значение убиралось и прибавлялось новое

Tags: c#, wpf, radiobutton

При выборе другого radiobutton прошлый выбранный вычитывался из цены

На примере кофе машины:
XAML

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,6,0">
                    <Label Content="Выберите размер стаканчика"
                           FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                           FontSize="18">
                        <Label.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect/>
                        </Label.Effect>
                    </Label>
    
                    <StackPanel>
                        <RadioButton Content="Маленький 0.3"
                                 FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                                 FontSize="14" 
                                 FontStyle="Italic"
                                 Height="25" 
                                 GroupName="CupSize" 
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 Background="#FF4C2B2B"
                                 Click="rb_mincup"
                                 x:Name="smallcup"
                                 Checked="smallcup_Checked"                         
                                 />
    
                        <RadioButton Content="Средний 0.5"
                                 FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                                 FontSize="14" 
                                 Height="25" 
                                 FontStyle="Italic"
                                 GroupName="CupSize"
                                 Background="#FF4C2B2B"
                                 BorderBrush="Black"  
                                 Click="rb_05cup"
                                 x:Name="middlecup"
                                 />
                        <RadioButton Content="Большой 0.7"
                                 FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                                 FontSize="14" 
                                 Height="25" 
                                 FontStyle="Italic"
                                 GroupName="CupSize"
                                 Background="#FF4C2B2B"
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                     x:Name="bigcuo07"
                                 Click="rb_bigcup"
                                 />
                        <RadioButton Content="Очень большой 1.0"
                                 FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                                 FontSize="14" 
                                 Height="25" 
                                 FontStyle="Italic"
                                 GroupName="CupSize"
                                 Background="#FF4C2B2B"
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 Click="rb_verybigcup"
                                 />
                    </StackPanel>
    
                    <Label Content="Выберите напиток"
                           FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                           FontSize="18">
                        <Label.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect/>
                        </Label.Effect>
                    </Label>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <RadioButton Content="Экспрессо"
                                 FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                                 FontSize="14" 
                                 FontStyle="Italic"
                                 GroupName="TypeDrink" 
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 Background="#FF4C2B2B"
                                 Height="25" Checked="RadioButton_Checked"/>
                        <RadioButton Content="Американо"
                                 FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                                 FontSize="14" 
                                 FontStyle="Italic"
                                 GroupName="TypeDrink"
                                 Background="#FF4C2B2B"
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 Height="25" Checked="RadioButton_Checked_1"/>
                        <RadioButton Content="Капучино"
                                 FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                                 FontSize="14" 
                                 FontStyle="Italic"
                                 GroupName="TypeDrink"
                                 Background="#FF4C2B2B"
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 Height="25" Checked="RadioButton_Checked_2"/>
                        <RadioButton Content="Маккиато"
                                 FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                                 FontSize="14" 
                                 FontStyle="Italic"
                                 GroupName="TypeDrink"
                                 Background="#FF4C2B2B"
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 Height="25" Checked="RadioButton_Checked_3"/>
                        <RadioButton Content="Латте"
                                 FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                                 FontSize="14" 
                                 FontStyle="Italic"
                                 GroupName="TypeDrink"
                                 Background="#FF4C2B2B"
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 Height="25" Checked="RadioButton_Checked_4"/>
                        <RadioButton Content="Раф"
                                 FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                                 FontSize="14" 
                                 FontStyle="Italic"
                                 GroupName="TypeDrink"
                                 Background="#FF4C2B2B"
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 Height="25" Checked="RadioButton_Checked_5"/>
                        <RadioButton Content="Чай"
                                 FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                                 FontSize="14" 
                                 FontStyle="Italic"
                                 GroupName="TypeDrink"
                                 Background="#FF4C2B2B"
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 Height="25" Checked="RadioButton_Checked_6"/>
                        <RadioButton Content="Сок"
                                 FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                                 FontSize="14" 
                                 FontStyle="Italic"
                                 GroupName="TypeDrink"
                                 Background="#FF4C2B2B"
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 Height="25" Checked="RadioButton_Checked_7"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel >
                        <Label Content="Количество сахара"
                           FontFamily="Comic Sans Ms"
                           FontSize="18">
                            <Label.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect/>
                            </Label.Effect>
                        </Label>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Height="20"
                                Width="20"
                                Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                Content="--" 
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                Click="Btn_minusSugar"/>
                            <Label Content="0"
                               x:Name="countsugar"/>
                            <Button Height="20"
                                Width="20"
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                Content="++" 
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                Click="Btn_plusSugar"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">

            <TextBlock Text="Цена:  "
                       FontFamily="Comic sams MS"
                       FontSize="25" 
                       FontStyle="Italic"
                       />
           
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" 
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
            
                
                <TextBox Text="0"
                           FontSize="20"
                           FontFamily="comic sans ms"
                           x:Name="resultPrice" 
                           FontStyle="Italic"
                           TextChanged="resultPrice_TextChanged"
                           Background="Transparent"
                           BorderBrush="Transparent"
                           IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

C#

```
 private void Btn_plusSugar(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int _countSugar = Convert.ToInt32(countsugar.Content);
        _countSugar = _countSugar + 1;
        countsugar.Content = _countSugar;
        if (_countSugar >=5)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Извините мы не кладем в кофе больше 5 сахара","Уведомление");
            _countSugar = 5;
        }
        countsugar.Content = _countSugar;
    }

    private void Btn_minusSugar(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int _countSugar = Convert.ToInt32(countsugar.Content);
        _countSugar = _countSugar - 1;
        countsugar.Content = _countSugar;
        if (_countSugar < 0)
        {
            
            _countSugar = 0;
        }
        countsugar.Content = _countSugar;
    }

    private void RadioButton_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int price = Convert.ToInt32(resultPrice.Text);
        price = price + 70;
        resultPrice.Text = price.ToString();
    }

    private void RadioButton_Checked_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int price = Convert.ToInt32(resultPrice.Text);
        price = price + 80;
        resultPrice.Text = price.ToString();
    }
```

У меня только прибавление, а хотелось бы ещё чтобы прошлое выбранное вычитывалось из итоговой цены
Пример:
Я выбираю сначала маленький кофе (Цена 50)
Потом выбираю экспрессо (цена ставится 140)
Передумываю и выбираю Латте (у меня становится 260, а нужно чтобы было 170)

Comment: Код вы конечно же не покажете?

Comment: Показывать нечего, просто radio button, внутри только нерабочий код

Comment: Привяжите их к одному свойству, у которого в set будет вызываться метод обновления цены, вот и весь ваш код...

Comment: Какой ответ вы ожидаете? Ни кода, не требований к логике. Гадание по скриншоту будем проводить?  XAML разметку даже не показали. Зато сумели перекрасить интерфейс. Написание приложения всегда начинайте с реализации его функций, и только потом, когда всё заработает, принимайтесь за свистелки с перделками и красоту. Опишите задачу, которую решаете, человеческими словами, с формулами по которым хотите вычислять.

Comment: @aepot Прошу прощения, сейчас добавлю все необходимое

Comment: Так гораздо лучше, чуть позже гляну код. Или кто-то другой поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужен здесь никакой код для того, чтобы понять и решить эту задачу.

Не нужно ничего вычитать. Просто текущую цену заменяете новой. Допустим, есть несколько категорий: основной продукт, сахар, молоко. Итоговая стоимость равна сумме стоимостей категорий. В каждой категории может быть выбрано только одно значение со своей стоимостью. Сделали новый выбор - подсчитали итоговую стоимость.

Comment: Вопрос не относится ни к какому языку программироваия, библиотеке, инструменту разработки и т. п. Сначала нужно решить задачу, а потом уже программировать её решение.

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо проверить вы выбрали или нет элемент

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender; // приводим отправителя к элементу типа CheckBox
    if (checkBox.Checked == true)
    {
        // выбрали экспрессо
        price += 70;
    }
    else
    {
       //  отказались от экспрессо
        price -= 70;
    }      
}
```

кода вы снимаете флажок с элемента он становиться "checkBox.Checked == false" когда выбираете "checkBox.Checked == true"

если возникли вопросы напишите